# Restkit entity relationship from two different responses based on url params

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, restkit

I have two different urls:

```
/getPosts
```

and

```
/getCommentsForPost?postId={id}
```

with these responses:

```
{
  "post": {
    "postId":1,
    "title":"lorem ipsum"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "comment" : {
    "commentId" : 123,
    "text" : "lorem ipsum"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the comment object doesn't have a postId property.

And these are my questions:

1. Is it possible to create entity relationships between responses from two different requests via RestKit and Core Data?
2. How (and when) can I read postId from my second url and set it in my Comment model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you use foreign key mapping.
2. You get a set of metadata to use during mapping (['Metadata Mapping' in this doc](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMappingOperation.html)).

Your life is more difficult because the id is a query parameter rather than being part of the URL path which is more RESTful. You might need to have RestKit map the URL or the URL query (`@metadata.HTTP.request.URL.query`) and then have a transient attribute that reads the appropriate information from that data.